# How to use mercurial patch queues on BitBucket

Tags: mercurial, bitbucket

Can you use mercurial patch queues with BitBucket after it has got it's new design?

Before you could press on the "Patch queue" link in a repository to create a patch queue, but that link seems to be gone now. Am I missing something?

I am using mercurial to manage a set of patches I need to run some software on my own machines, in short the method outlined [here](http://dwm.suckless.org/customisation/patch_queue). I've been using this method for some time and I've also wondered if there's an easier way to do it with git?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that patch queues are treated as forks in Bitbucket now.  To create a patch queue click on the `Fork` button then click on the `create a patch queue` link on the top right of the fork page.

You can then administer the patch queue by clicking on the `Fork` link on the `Overview` page and managing it as you would any other repository.